# How to do a simple maths percetange calculation correctly in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, math, percentage

Can this equation be reworked to a correctly formatted string?

```
Dim Total = MyNumber / 100 * MyVAT
```

Produces error:

```
"Input string was not in a correct format"
```

Comment: what output you required?

Comment: just an integer. I am missing something simple as I just get "Input string was not in a correct format" error.

Comment: what format will you like examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: What is the Value of MyNumber and MyVat?

Comment: It is currency so 0.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really set `Option Strict` to `on`. Then this would never compile since `MyNumber` is a string(as you've commented).

You should first ensure that the input is numeric, for example with `Decimal.TryParse`:

```
Dim Total As Decimal
Dim num As Decimal 
If Decimal.TryParse(MyNumber, num) Then
    Total = num / 100 * MyVAT
End If
```

Now you can use `Decimal.ToString(format)` to convert it to a string with the desired format. For example(assuming you want two decimal places):

```
Dim output As String = Total.ToString("N2")
```

[**Standard Numeric Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

try with this statement

```
 Dim Total = Val(MyNumber) / 100 * Val(MyVAT)
```

Answer (score 0):

use like below

```
Total.ToString("#")
```

More Detail:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/0c899ak8.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2