# vb.net error while calculating percentage of the number

Tags: vb.net

Hi i am trying to create a percentage of a number.

When the user enters the number it should find what is 18 % of that number.

code :

```
If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then

            tax += saleprice / 100 * 0.18
        End If
```

HOW CAN I FINT THE 18% of a price in vb.net ???? Any formulas ?
but when i enter it it is not correctly entered in the database so i don't get any result help. Note : the sale price and the tax are declared at the top of the class.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
  Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into pos.artikli(kod,ime,mera,kol,nabavna,profit,prodazna,tax,dolgopis,dolgopis2,proizvoditel,mkproizvod) values ('" & TextBoxKod.Text & "','" & TextBoxNaziv.Text & "','" & edmera & "','" & kolicina & "','" & TextBoxNabavna.Text & "','" & procentdobivka & "','" & TextBoxProdazna.Text & "','" & tax & "','" & TextBoxOpis.Text & "','" & TextBoxOpis2.Text & "','" & TextBoxProizvoditel.Text & "','" & mkpr & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: Is that how you would figure the tax on something using a pencil and paper?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]....thats *not* the correct way to build SQL BTW

Comment: See this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143839/how-to-do-a-simple-maths-percetange-calculation-correctly-in-vb-net ,hope helps.

Comment: If you don't use sql parameters, you are going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 0):

Hint / example:

```
    'http://www.convertit.com/Go/ConvertIt/Calculators/Finance/Sales_Tax_Calc.ASP
    Dim tax As Decimal
    Dim test() As Decimal = {1D, 100D, 1000D}
    Dim taxrate As Decimal = 18D / 100D '18%

    For Each saleprice As Decimal In test
        tax = saleprice * taxrate
    Next
```